# Как инициализируются глобальные переменные в зависимости от платформы?

Tags: golang, случайные-числа

В пакете `crypto/rand` объявлена переменная `Reader` интерфейсного типа `io.Reader`. Когда эта переменная инициализируется? Компилятором в зависимости от платформы? Где в исходном коде компилятора «блок инициализации» подобных переменных?

Comment: math/rand может?

Comment: просто там нет ни Reader и ни io.Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим [исходники `crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/).

Несложный поиск по исходным текстам этого пакета показывает, что сия переменная инициализируется, как и все подобные переменные уровня пакета, в функции с именем [`init`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init)

Если бы вы открыли [исходники пакета `crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/), вы увидели бы там [файл `rand.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand.go), файлы [`rand_unux.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand_unix.go) и [`rand_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand_windows.go)

В первом файле вы нашли бы объявление переменной `Reader`:

```go
// Reader is a global, shared instance of a cryptographically
// secure random number generator.
//
// On Linux and FreeBSD, Reader uses getrandom(2) if available, /dev/urandom otherwise.
// On OpenBSD, Reader uses getentropy(2).
// On other Unix-like systems, Reader reads from /dev/urandom.
// On Windows systems, Reader uses the CryptGenRandom API.
// On Wasm, Reader uses the Web Crypto API.
var Reader io.Reader
```

В файлах `rand_unix.go` и `rand_windows.go` вы нашли бы, как именно эта переменная инициализируется:

```
/* rand_linux.go */
// Easy implementation: read from /dev/urandom.
// This is sufficient on Linux, OS X, and FreeBSD.

func init() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "plan9" {
        Reader = newReader(nil)
    } else {
        Reader = &devReader{name: urandomDevice}
    }
}
```

```
/* rand_windows.go */
// Implemented by using Windows CryptoAPI 2.0.

func init() { Reader = &rngReader{} }
```

Ну хорошо, функцию `init` с инициализацией глобальной переменной мы нашли. Их оказалось **две**. Как компилятор Go выберет нужную функцию `init`?

Во время сборки Go использует [два метода](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_constraints) для определения того, нужно ли компилировать файл, или пропустить.

Первый метод называется *build tag*. Например, если вы откроете файл `rand_unix.go`, вы найдёте там комментарий

```
// +build aix darwin dragonfly freebsd linux netbsd openbsd plan9 solaris
```

Этот комментарий требует от `go build` компилировать файл если при компиляции был указан один из тегов `aix darwin dragonfly freebsd linux netbsd openbsd plan9 solaris`. Теги можно указывать самостоятельно при запуске `go build`, кроме того, теги с названием операционной системы и аппаратной платформы (`386`, `arm` и т.п.) устанавливаются автоматически.

Второй метод - включить имя операционной системы и платформы в название файла.

Этот метод используется в пакете `crypto/rand` несколько раз:

- `rand_linux.go` - компилируется ТОЛЬКО в том случае, когда значение
  переменной окружения `GOOS` равно `linux`
- `rand_openbsd.go` -
  компилируется ТОЛЬКО в том случае, когда значение переменной
  окружения `GOOS` равно `openbsd`
- `rand_windows.go` - компилируется
  ТОЛЬКО в том случае, когда значение переменной окружения `GOOS` равно
  `windows`

Переменная `GOOS` устанавливается автоматически. Вы можете её установить самостоятельно, если вам хочется собрать бинарник для другой платформы. Например, виндовый на линуксе.

В `crypto/rand` используются оба метода. На платформе MS Windows будет скомпилирован файл `rand_windows.go` по правилу именования файлов, а файл `rand_unix.go` будет проигнорирован, так как тег `windows` отсутствует в списке тегов `+build`

Соответственно, на платформе linux или OS X файл с именем `rand_windows.go` будет проигнорирован из-за неподходящего имени, зато файл `rand_unix.go` будет скомпилирован благодаря подходящему тегу в списке `+build`.

Вы можете спросить: "А как же `rand_batched.go`? Почему он компилируется и в линуксе, и в винде?"

Дело в том, что суффикс `batched` не совпадает ни с одной из операционных систем, с которыми знаком Go. Списки известных ОС и аппаратных платформ закодированы в [`go/build/syslist.go`](https://golang.org/src/go/build/syslist.go)
Если суффикс файла не указан в списке `goosList`, к этому файлу не применяются правила условной компиляции по имени файла.

Как-то так.